# PyQT,how i use qimage for convert videos to gui in 32-bit?

Tags: opencv, pyqt, pyqt4

I capture videos from OpenCV. I want it to display on gui in 32-bit but it showing 24-bit. I try to change `image2 = QtGui.QImage(img0.data, width, height, bpl, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)` to `image2 = QtGui.QImage(img0.data, width, height, bpl, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)`

It show message error `QImage: out of memory, returning null image”`

[my video output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ6WU.png)  i don't need this output,i need it display original colour. how i fix this problem?

Note: i use PyQT4 and OpenCV3 library.

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

    """self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self)
    self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

    self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
    self.textBrowser.append("This is a QTextBrowser!")

    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)"""
    self.left = 700
    self.top = 400
    self.width = 1920
    self.height = 1080

    self.setWindowTitle('Sender')
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    self.setFixedSize(1920,1080)

    self.videoFrame = ImageWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.videoFrame)


    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateImage)
    self.timer.start(30)
    self.capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def updateImage(self):
    _, img0 = self.capture1.read()
    height, width, bpc = img0.shape
    bpl = bpc * width
    image2 = QtGui.QImage(img0.data, width, height, bpl, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    pixmap2 = image2.scaled(300, 300, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    self.videoFrame2.setImage(pixmap2)

class ImageWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(ImageWidget,self).__init__(parent)
    self.image=None

def setImage(self,image):
    self.image=image
    sz=image.size()
    self.setMinimumSize(sz)
    self.update()

def paintEvent(self,event):
    qp=QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)
    if self.image:
        qp.drawImage(QtCore.QPoint(150,150 ),self.image)
    qp.end()
```

Comment: "I want it to display on gui in 32-bit but it showing 24-bit." Do you expect your video to contain transparency? Or what's the point?

Comment: Probably try with Format_ARGB32 ?

Comment: I try Fortat_ARGB32 but it did not work. It still show the same error.

Comment: The video output from my code did not same  the original color. It alomost blue in the video. So i try to capture video without use gui then we get the correct color.